# Dynamically load and render react component with input[type=file]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to load a react js component dynamically through an html file input. Essentially, I'd like to achieve the same effect as if I had done `import Foo from ./foo.js`

I can read the file as text after the onChange event of the html element, but then I don't know what to do with it? Is it even possible to achieve my goal? Thanks!

```
onChange(e) {
  var fr = new FileReader()

  fr.addEventListener('load', f => {
    window.console.log(f.target.result.substring(0, 500))
    // yields: import React, { Component } from 'react' ... class Foo extends Component { ...
    // but now what?
  })

  fr.readAsText(e.target.files[0])
}
```

Comment: You'd have to use some kind of `eval`. However, the problem will be that the file contains constructors (such as `import`) that the browser doesn't understand.

Comment: @FelixKling hhmmm.. I hadn't considered that imports would screw things up. May have to limit this to stateless functional components.

Comment: Looks like [babel-standalone](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone) has some potential!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up getting this to work with [babel-standalone](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone). I'm only able to use stateless, functional components, however, and I feel as though my implementation could be improved. For example, I don't like how I have to `string.prototype.replace`.

Anyway, here's what worked for me, hopefully it might help you, too.

```
// fileToBeLoaded.js
const elem = () => <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

// foo.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { transform } from 'babel-standalone'

class Foo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            elem: undefined
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        let fr = new FileReader()

        fr.addEventListener('load', e1 => {
            let s = e1.target.result
            let result = transform(s, {
                presets: ['es2015'],
                plugins: ['transform-react-jsx']
             })

             let s1 = result.replace(`'use strict';

             let elem = function elem(props) {`, 'elem = function(props) {')

             let elem = () => {}
             elem = eval(s1)

             this.setState({elem})
        })

        fr.readAsText(e.target.files[0])
    }

    render() {
        const Elem = this.state.elem ? this.state.elem : () => <h1>No elem!</h1>
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="file" onChange={this.handleChange}
                <Elem />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```